# R: Plotting the percentage of pair combinations in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I have the following `dataframe`:

```
df <-read.table(header=TRUE, text="id Medication
                1 A
                1 B
                1 C
                2 A
                2 B
                3 A
                3 A
                3 B
                4 B
                4 C")
```

I would like to plot in a bar chart the percentage of individuals with each par of medications: A&B, B&C, and C&D. In this example, it would be:

```
A&B = 0.75, B&C = 0.5, and A&C = 0.25.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `combn` to calculate ratio for each combination.

```
data <- do.call(rbind, combn(unique(df$Medication), 2, function(x) 
  data.frame(Med_comb = paste(x, collapse = ' & '), 
             value = mean(tapply(df$Medication, df$id, function(y) all(x %in% y)))), 
  simplify = FALSE))

data
#  Med_comb value
#1    A & B  0.75
#2    A & C  0.25
#3    B & C  0.50
```

For plotting you can use `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(Med_comb, value)) + geom_col()
```

[image]